# Not able to load data from .csv file to mysql database using shell script

Tags: mysql, load

I am not able to load data from .csv file to MySQL database using shell script, I am using this command in Linux to import data:

```
mysql -utest -ptest123 --local_infile -e "use testing; LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '20160821-105501.cap.csv' INTO TABLE DataPackets FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' IGNORE 1 LINES;"
```

But I always get stuck getting this sign ">"

I want to use the above command in shell script to automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in shell as follow, I haven't tried but it may work for you..

`mysql -utest -ptest123 --local_infile << END
use testing; LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '20160821-105501.cap.csv' INTO TABLE DataPackets FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' IGNORE 1 LINES;
END`

Hope it helps!